# mysql join отсутствие во второй таблице

Tags: mysql, join

Есть запрос: `SELECT image.image_id, offer_id FROM shop_item_param_image LEFT JOIN image ON shop_item_param_image.value = image.image_id`

И 2 таблицы.

shop_item_param_image (offer_id, param_id, value) и image (image_id)

Необходимо переделать запрос так, чтобы он выдавал offer_id из первой таблицы, если во второй нет смежных записей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT shop_item_param_image.offer_id 
FROM shop_item_param_image 
LEFT JOIN image ON shop_item_param_image.value = image.image_id
WHERE image.image_id IS NULL
```